# Получение и нажатие на случайную кнопку (Android)

Tags: java, android

Есть 4 кнопки. Надо нажать на них случайным образом. Для этого дал всем кнопкам похожие имена с разницей на один номер. Примерно так:

```
        ImageView knopka1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageView knopka2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView knopka3= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        ImageView knopka4= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
```

Для получении случайной кнопки генерировал случайное число от 1 до 4 соединил это число со словом knopka. Таким образом у меня есть случайная кнопка.

```
while (i <= level)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int counter = random.nextInt(4)+1;
            String knopka = "knopka"+String.valueOf(counter);
            knopka.performClick();
        }
```

Но нажать на эту кнопку не получается. В PHP это можно сделать с легкостью но или Java или Android Studio это не понимает. Или есть другой метод про которого я не знаю. Как это можно сделать?

PS. При этом я должен обязательно получить последовательность нажатий. По этому и использовал числа для выбора случайной кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте switch-case конструкцию, нечто вроде этого:

```
while (i <= level)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int counter = random.nextInt(4)+1;
            switch(counter){
              case 1: knopka.performClick(); (используете кнопку 1)
               break;
              case 2: ......
               break;
             }
            String knopka = "knopka"+String.valueOf(counter);

        }
```

Псевдокод, но надеюсь мысль поняли.

Answer (score 1):

В яве не получится генерировать имена переменным в момент исполнения, т.к. код компилируется до исполнения и динамически его не изменить.

Вам надо зайти с другой стороны - создать массив кнопок и обращаться к ним через массив, а ещё лучше через `ArrayList` как-то так:

```
ArrayList<View> arrayOfViews = new ArrayList<>();

ImageView knopka1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ImageView knopka2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
ImageView knopka3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
ImageView knopka4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

arrayOfViews.add(knopka1);
arrayOfViews.add(knopka2);
arrayOfViews.add(knopka3);
arrayOfViews.add(knopka4);

//Теперь можно обращаться к кнопкам как по имени переменно, так и по индексу в списке:
int someRandomInt = new Random().nextInt(arrayOfViews.size());
arrayOfViews.get(someRandomInt).performClick();
```